# SWIFT - prevent same function from being called concurrently

Tags: swift

I have an application where the main UI waits for some calculation to be done before updating. The whole application depends solely on the user's connectivity to wifi as we are making any api calls to calculate the data. Sometimes, in RARE conditions, the function that runs everything gets executed twice... causing the updated UI to display invalid data.

What are some ways i can prevent this from happening. Sorry i'm not showing code because it'll be easier to explain the concept.

Edit: To reproduce this error, this is what i do. Pseudocode below

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    mainCall()
}


override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    mainCall()
}


func executeOne(){
    callA(){}
    callB(){}
    etc...
}
```

Comment: Set a flag when the method is running and check it at the beginning of the method.

Comment: Please post some code so that others can get the idea of what's happening?

Comment: "Sorry i'm not showing code" Me too. It's silly to ask a question like this and expect people to answer blind. Work out what the key code needed to reproduce the issue is, and show it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a bool variable to indicate whether an API call is already in progress or not and only trigger an API call in case another one is not in progress.

```
class YourClass {
    var apiCallIsInProgress = false

    func apiCall(){
        if !apiCallIsInProgress {
            // doApiCall is the function actually implementing the API call and returning the result through a completion handler
            doApiCall(completion: {
                apiCallIsInProgress = false
            }
        } else {
            apiCallIsInProgress = true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: True, but yuck. And what about threading issues? Seems much better to use DispatchQueue `sync` as a lock. And even that won't help if (as we have reason to suspect) the API stuff happens asynchronously.

Comment: Yes, also i tried this and it didn't completely solve the issue. The other process still gets run